# Newton's Method in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is the function I need to program:

f(x) = 1 – e^cos(x)

1. Use Newton’s method to approximate the root of f near to 4. Use 10-5 as the kick out threshold.

This is how the professor wrote it out for class in another example, so I just copied the same thing using function in this problem:

```
f[x_] = 1 - E^Cos[x];
a = 4;
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]

i = 1;
While[i <= 1000,
 g[x_] = D[f[x], x];
 b = a - f[a]/g[a];
 a = b;
 c = Abs[a - prev a]
   If[c < 10^-5,
    i = 10000;
    i++
    ];]
Print[a];
Print[f[a]];
Print[i];
```

My problem is that it is not iterating the approximate root. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are missing a semi colon after `c = Abs[a - prev a]`

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few typos, plus `prev a` need defining.

```
f[x_] = 1 - E^Cos[x];
a = 4;
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}] 

i = 1;
While[i <= 1000,
 g[x_] = D[f[x], x];
 b = a - f[a]/g[a];
 preva = a;
 a = N[b];
 c = Abs[a - preva];
  If[c < 10^-5,
  i = 10000,
  i++];] 
Print[a];
Print[f[a]];
Print[i];
```